# Maintaining a large website

Tags: deployment, version-control

When I update a website I just replace the content with a new file.

How do larger websites update their content? When thousands of visitors are viewing the site.

How do example, how do Facebook or Twitter do it? Thousands of developers working and millions of visitors on the website. Are they working on a duplicate of the website and then switching the DNS? Are they using Git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blue-Green is a widely used deployment strategy that avoids downtime.

First of, you need a router/load balancer that can forward requests to a Virtual IP to an actual machine. Where I work, we use [F5](https://f5.com/products).

You must also have two production environments, called "blue" and "green".

Only one of them is "live" at any time.
By this, I mean that your router must forward all incoming requests to either the "blue" environment, **or** the "green" environment.

Let's say "green" is live, and you need to release a new version of your app to production.

1. You deploy your new content/application to your "blue" environment (remember, no requests are being routed here, so the environment is "offline")
2. Then you test your "blue" environment and make sure everything's been deployed correctly before going live.
3. Then you change your router to forward all requests to your new and stable "blue" env.

If after going live you discover there's a bug, simply rollback by changing your router again to route all requests to your "green" environment, with the "old" application.

More about blue-green deployments here: [BlueGreenDeployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)

Another well known deployment strategy is the Canary Release, which enables new features for a small number of users, and once everything's been tested properly, it's enabled for all users.

Comment: @Mana As far as I know, yes, this is very common. Canary release is also widely used - Facebook uses it to enable new features for a small number of users, before going "live" for everyone. That's why sometimes your facebook homepage may look different than your friend's facebook homepage - because they're testing new stuff. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Very interesting! I will read up on Canary release and BlueGreenDeployment! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

They are working all with versioning systems like Git, SVN etc. So they can work in a team of different functions and push and review commits for being pulled on the live environment (pull requests). Also, the big sites have a really big testing infrastructure also.

Comment: As a Live Environment and a Testing Environment.

Comment: @holpducki: Yes, I think I just have said this :-)

Comment: That doesn't explain how they're able to deploy new content without going offline, which I think is the core of the question.